# Fix values that are typed into a doublespinbox in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to create a doublespin box that changes values in steps of 0.2. But when the user enters a value that is not correct according to the steps. I normalizes that to the nearest correct value.

I tried something like the code shown below but I don't know how to stop values like 0.5 to be entered. Please help me on this.

```
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *

    class SigSlot(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.setWindowTitle('spinbox value')
            self.resize(250,150)
            self.lcd1 = QLCDNumber(self)
            self.spinbox1 = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
            self.spinbox1.setSingleStep(0.2)
            self.spinbox1.setCorrectionMode(1)
             # create a Grid Layout
            grid = QGridLayout()
            grid.addWidget(self.lcd1, 0, 0)
            grid.addWidget(self.spinbox1, 1, 0)
            self.setLayout(grid)
             # allows access to the spinbox value as it changes
            self.connect(self.spinbox1, SIGNAL('valueChanged(double)'), self.change_value1)

        def change_value1(self, event):
            val = self.spinbox1.value()
            self.lcd1.display(val)

    app = QApplication([])
    qb = SigSlot()
    qb.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices:

- You can subclass the `QSpinBox`, override `validate` method and use an appropriate `Q*Validator` (e.g. `QRegExpValidator`) inside.
- You can check the value in slot connected to `valueChanged` before using and correct it if necessary.

Since you are already using the `valueChanged` signal, second option should be fairly easy to implement. Just change your `change_value` method like this:

```
def change_value1(self, val): # new value is passed as an argument
    # so no need for this
    # val = self.spinbox1.value()

    new_val = round(val*5)/5 # one way to fix
    if val != new_val:       # if value is changed, put it in the spinbox
        self.spinbox1.setValue(new_val)

    self.lcd1.display(new_val)
```

By the way, since you are using only one decimal precision, it might be logical to also use:

```
self.spinbox1.setDecimals(1)
```

in your `__init__`. And try to use the [new style signals and slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html). i.e.:

```
self.connect(self.spinbox1, SIGNAL('valueChanged(double)'), self.change_value1)
```

could be written as:

```
self.spinbox1.valueChanged[float].connect(self.change_value1)
```

**Edit**

Subclassing:

```
class MySpinBox(QDoubleSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MySpinBox, self).__init__(parent)
        # any RegExp that matches the allowed input
        self.validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("\\d+[\\.]{0,1}[02468]{0,1}"), self)

    def validate(self, text, pos):
        # this decides if the entered value should be accepted
        return self.validator.validate(text, pos)
```

then instead of using `QDoubleSpinBox` you would use `MySpinBox` and leave the input checking to this class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you elaborate more on the first method about creating a subclass and then overriding the validator method. Because this was just a sample program I created to demo the problem.

Comment: @Kakashi: Oops, my regex skills are rusted :). Updated with the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In your change value method you can do something like this

```
val = round(self.spinbox1.value(), 1)
if val/2*10 - int(val/2*10):
    val = round(val, 1) + .1
```

It's probably not the best way but it works.